# extract virtualhosts to individual files based on virtual hostname

Tags: awk, sed

I want to extract each VirtualHost from  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf and put then into their own config files

there are lot of entries in 1 single file and managing them is becoming problem day by day, however, moving them to separate file per virtualhost is easy to work and manage.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName www.customer1.com
    ServerAlias customer1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/customer1
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
    SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLProxyEngine off
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl_certs/customer1.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl_certs/customer1.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl_certs/customer1.inter.cert
    <Directory /var/www/customer1>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

I'm trying something like this, but it doesn't let me isolate based on ServerName Value.

`awk '/^<VirtualHost/{flag=1}/^<\/VirtualHost/{print $2;flag=0}flag' /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. If you have "lot of entries", please, provide an example with at least 2 complete entries and show the expected and actual result matching this input.

Comment: If this is Debian (or Debian-derived) you are supposed to have each virtual host in its own file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. You then use `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` to bring them in or out of the configuration as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Given a file named file.txt with the following input:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName name1

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName name2

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName name3

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName name4

</VirtualHost>
```

and a script with the name get-virtual-host.sh with the contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: get-virtual-host.sh <filename> <ServerName>"
    exit 1
fi

sed -ne "/^<VirtualHost/{x;:cycle n; /ServerName/{/ServerName[[:space:]]\+$2/!{s/.*//; x; d}}; /<\/VirtualHost/{H;x;p;q}; H; bcycle}" $1
```

then you can fetch the VirtualHost section by specifying a parameter like this:

```
get-virtual-host.sh file.txt name2
```

which outputs

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName name2

</VirtualHost>
```

Is this what you need?

Sed script explained as requested:

The sed command says:

If there is a line that starts with *<VirtualHost*, do the following:

1. Exchange the pattern space with the hold space
2. read next input line
3. if it contains the word *ServerName*, check if the value of ServerName is equal to parameter 2 given to the script
4. if not equal, delete everything in the pattern space, exchange pattern and holdspace, delete pattern space and start the sed command with the next input line.
5. if equal, check if the input line contains the end tag *</VirtualHost*
6. if so, append a newline to the holdspace, append the pattern space to the hold space, exchange pattern and holdspace, print the contents and quit
7. otherwise, append a newline to the holdspace and add the contents of the pattern space to the holdspace and jump to label cycle (step 2. above)

Comment: I updated the script so you can specify the filename as a parameter

Comment: Could you please explain that long complicated sed syntax?

Comment: If you have long, complicated sed syntax then you don't need to explain it, you need to get rid of it as you're using the wrong tool. Whatever the sed script in question does could be done some combination of more concisely, robustly, efficiently, and.or portably with awk. If the OP provides some concise, testable sample input and expected output [as requested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608623/extract-virtualhosts-to-individual-files-based-on-virtual-hostname#comment1135868_608623) then we can help them.

Comment: @EdMorton
You are right, I also don't like these long sed scripts. I will dive deeper into awk in the future, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Effectively you want to split the file at every `<VirtualHost` , then rename them according to the `ServerName` value.

**Step 1: splitting the file**

```
csplit -z -f vhost_ '/<VirtualHost/' '{*}'
```

`csplit` allows file splitting at a given pattern match, here `<VirtualHost`, the options included are: `-f vhost_` name resulting files with this prefix (new files will be `vhost_00`, `vhost_01`, ....), `-z` do not create empty files, `{*}` split at every pattern match. More to be found in `man csplit`

**Step 2: renaming the files**

A simple bash routine should do the trick:

```
for f in vhost_??
  do mv $f $(grep ServerName $f | awk '{print $2".conf"}')
done
```

You seem to be familiar with `awk` and `bash` so not explained.

Answer (score -1):

**@Juxtaposed -- I know you from unix.com groups ... You are the expert in these things**

the solution works perfectly fine for me -- except I had to

```
egrep -v "^$|^#" default-ssl.conf|egrep ServerName |while read S N
do
./get-virtual-host.sh default-ssl.conf $N > configs/$N.conf
done
```

and some of the files are empty -- but I can live with that -- only 2 were of 0 size, although they were also complete vhosts.

Anyways, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please use the tick-mark beside the voting buttons to accept Juxtaposed's answer, since it worked for you

Comment: if you copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell you about **some** of the issues but not all of them. See [the first comment you got](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608623/extract-virtualhosts-to-individual-files-based-on-virtual-hostname#comment1135868_608623) for how to get help with your problem.